# knockoutjs bind list of items to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I have this dropdown control:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_' + $index() }, 
                   options: TeacherNames(), 
                   optionsValue: 'TeacherId', 
                   optionsText: 'TeacherName', 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher', 
                   event: { change: $root.permissionChanged }">
</select>
```

And then I'm trying to set the values in the dropdown via:

```
item.TeacherNames = ko.computed(function() {
  return getTeacherList(item.OrderId);
});

function getTeacherList(orderId) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/WebServiceTeacher.asmx/GetTeachersForMyAccount",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'Id': " + JSON.stringify(orderId) + "}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.d) {
        return data.d;
      }
    },
    error: function(n) {
      alert('Error');
    }
  });
}
```

I'm able to get the teacher data back from the web service but I'm not able to actually set the values in the select list.

The select control is part of foreach binding:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Orders -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 m-t-20">
    <hr class="blue" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row order-gray-bk col-wrap">
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 n-m-t m-r-10 p-t-10 p-b-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 n-p">
            Teacher:
            <select class="form-control" 
                    data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_' + $index() }, 
                               options: TeacherNames(), 
                               optionsValue: 'TeacherId', 
                               optionsText: 'TeacherName', 
                               optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher', 
                               event: { change: $root.permissionChanged }">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The call to the web service is triggered in foreach loop for each order:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.d, function(item) {
  item.TeacherNames = ko.computed(function() {
    return getTeacherList(item.OrderId);
  });
  self.Orders.push(item);
});
```

Comment: In my understanding, its because ajax request takes time. Try creating an observableArray and push data to it

Comment: @Rajesh pointed out right . instead of creating a computed & filling up `getTeacherList` alternatively  under success you can directly fill it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got things mixed up. A `computed` is meant for parts of your view models that change depending on other parts of your view model. The function inside the computed *is triggered **every** time Knockout feels the `computed` has to be re-evaluated*.

Instead, have a regular observableArray like this:

```
item.TeacherNames = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Then fill that array at a convenient time (page load, or when the user switches to a certain tab on your page, or when the orderId changes, or...):

```
function getTeacherList(orderId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/webservices/WebServiceTeacher.asmx/GetTeachersForMyAccount",
    data: "{'Id': " + JSON.stringify(orderId) + "}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      item.TeacherNames(data.TeacherNames);
    }
  });
}
```

As a specific example, if you want to refresh the teacher names when the orderId (assumed to be an `observable`) changes:

```
item.orderId.subscribe(function(newVal) {
  if (newVal !== item.orderId()) {
    getTeacherList(newVal);
  }
});
```

As a footnote, a computed observable would be good e.g. for showing the list sorted:

```
item.sortedTeacherNames = ko.computed(function() {
  return item.TeacherNames().sort();
});
```

That `sortedTeacherNames` will update *automatically* if you ever change the related `TeacherNames` observable array.

PS. If `TeacherNames` is a `computed` or a `observableArray` you can just do `options: TeacherNames` (without parentheses), as KO knows how to treat those types in a data binding.